# Android - cannot inherit from final GestureDetectorCompat

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I receive this error "cannot inherit from final GestureDetectorCompat" when I change the API version in gradle file.
If I use api 22 it works fine but if I use api 23 I've got this error, why?

Here is my code:
file ClickItemTouchListener.java

```
package com.ddfilms.dado.RecyclerView.Utils;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.view.GestureDetectorCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.MotionEventCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

abstract class ClickItemTouchListener implements OnItemTouchListener {
    private static final String LOGTAG = "ClickItemTouchListener";

    private final GestureDetectorCompat mGestureDetector;

    ClickItemTouchListener(RecyclerView hostView) {
        mGestureDetector = new ItemClickGestureDetector(hostView.getContext(),
                new ItemClickGestureListener(hostView));
    }

    private boolean isAttachedToWindow(RecyclerView hostView) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            return hostView.isAttachedToWindow();
        } else {
            return (hostView.getHandler() != null);
        }
    }

    private boolean hasAdapter(RecyclerView hostView) {
        return (hostView.getAdapter() != null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent event) {
        if (!isAttachedToWindow(recyclerView) || !hasAdapter(recyclerView)) {
            return false;
        }

        mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent event) {
        // We can silently track tap and and long presses by silently
        // intercepting touch events in the host RecyclerView.
    }

    abstract boolean performItemClick(RecyclerView parent, View view, int position, long id);

    abstract boolean performItemLongClick(RecyclerView parent, View view, int position, long id);

    private class ItemClickGestureDetector extends GestureDetectorCompat {
        private final ItemClickGestureListener mGestureListener;

        public ItemClickGestureDetector(Context context, ItemClickGestureListener listener) {
            super(context, listener);
            mGestureListener = listener;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            final boolean handled = super.onTouchEvent(event);

            final int action = event.getAction() & MotionEventCompat.ACTION_MASK;
            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                mGestureListener.dispatchSingleTapUpIfNeeded(event);
            }

            return handled;
        }
    }

    private class ItemClickGestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
        private final RecyclerView mHostView;
        private View mTargetChild;

        public ItemClickGestureListener(RecyclerView hostView) {
            mHostView = hostView;
        }

        public void dispatchSingleTapUpIfNeeded(MotionEvent event) {
            // When the long press hook is called but the long press listener
            // returns false, the target child will be left around to be
            // handled later. In this case, we should still treat the gesture
            // as potential item click.
            if (mTargetChild != null) {
                onSingleTapUp(event);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) {
            final int x = (int) event.getX();
            final int y = (int) event.getY();

            mTargetChild = mHostView.findChildViewUnder(x, y);
            return (mTargetChild != null);
        }

        @Override
        public void onShowPress(MotionEvent event) {
            if (mTargetChild != null) {
                mTargetChild.setPressed(true);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent event) {
            boolean handled = false;

            if (mTargetChild != null) {
                mTargetChild.setPressed(false);

                final int position = mHostView.getChildPosition(mTargetChild);
                final long id = mHostView.getAdapter().getItemId(position);
                handled = performItemClick(mHostView, mTargetChild, position, id);

                mTargetChild = null;
            }

            return handled;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent event, MotionEvent event2, float v, float v2) {
            if (mTargetChild != null) {
                mTargetChild.setPressed(false);
                mTargetChild = null;

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent event) {
            if (mTargetChild == null) {
                return;
            }

            final int position = mHostView.getChildPosition(mTargetChild);
            final long id = mHostView.getAdapter().getItemId(position);
            final boolean handled = performItemLongClick(mHostView, mTargetChild, position, id);

            if (handled) {
                mTargetChild.setPressed(false);
                mTargetChild = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ddfilms.dado"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 4
        versionName "2.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.manuelpeinado.fadingactionbar:fadingactionbar:3.1.2'
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:systembartint:1.0.3'
    compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.2.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-query-full.0.26.7.jar')
}
```

With this code it work, but if i change in gradle with api 23 i've got the error

```
...
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
...
        targetSdkVersion 23
...
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
...
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

rewrite GestureDetectorCompat.java, delete final like this:

```
public class GestureDetectorCompat {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'` in your app's `gradle.build` to

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
```

For more info check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37548116/cannot-inherit-from-final-gesturedetectorcompat/38033846#38033846) of mine.